# How to make change an imagebutton upon click

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am new to android and trying to figure out how i can have a different image upon click.
I have 2 images, one for the normal state and one for the onclick state. i am unable to set up the onclick state image.

Here's the code:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button_information"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="@drawable/em_info_active"
    android:background="@drawable/em_info_active"
    android:src="@drawable/em_info" />

<ImageButton   
    android:id="@+id/button_settings"
    android:layout_width="90dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button_information"
    android:background="@drawable/em_prefs_active"
    android:src="@drawable/em_prefs" />
```

and the corresponding java code is :

```
public void onClick(final View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {

        case R.id.button_information:
            leaveMainActivity();
            InformationActivity.newInstance(getActivity());
            break;
        case R.id.button_settings:
            leaveMainActivity();
            PreferencesActivity.newInstance(getActivity());
            break;
    }
}
```

Any clue how I can go about the same?
Thanks!
Justin

Comment: use selector as background where you will define drawable for state_pressed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a xml file in your drawable as imagebtn.xml and paste this code

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/your_imagename_while_focused"/>
<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/your_imagename_while_pressed" />
<item android:drawable="@drawable/image_name_while_notpressed" />  
</selector>
```

and try this in your activity

```
button_information.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.imagebtn);
```

The background image changes upon focussed and pressed. Let me know if this works.

Comment: do i have to create an imagebtn class with selector every single time i need to create a different button image or i can indent with item1,2 etc and call that in the activity class?\

Comment: you can just set the src to this file on an image button